# Is there a standard way to recover (factory configuration) an Android device?

Tags: android, recovery

I will soon starting to "play" with the kernel of an android tablet and I want to check first the recovery process in order to be able to recover the tablet in the factory configuration in case of kernel mishandling.

So, I am wondering if there is a standard way to recover an android device, or does each android device has its own recover process ?

Answer (score 0):

Settings -> Backup and reset -> Factory data reset

I think this is equivalent to wiping the /data and /cache partitions.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Here we suppose that the tablet correctly starts, but in case of kernel mishandling we can suppose that the tablet cannot start. I am searching for an standard hardware way to start from the backup partition.

Comment: You can wipe /data and /cache (probably using fastboot), and the device should re-create them with a factory reset next time it boots. If it still cannot boot, you'll have to reinstall the OS on it.